# SQL "IN" clause usage to include / exclude items at the same time?

Tags: sql, plsql

I would like to have some help on the best way to address a specific revision. I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODDTA.F4105
WHERE (COITM, COMCU) IN ((`"Set of Data 1"`))
    AND (COLOCN, COLEDG) NOT IN ((`"Set of Data 2"`));
```

What I want to do is to revise if there is someway to merge these items in one:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODDTA.F4105
WHERE (COITM, COMCU, COLOCN, COLEDG) IN ((`"Set of Data 1 & 2"`));
```

Do you know if this is achievable?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: Stackoverflow editting tip: You can just indent your multi-line code with 4 spaces (or highlight the block of code and hit the `{}` button at the top and it will indent for you) as opposed to wrapping it in backticks, which is really more appropriate for `in line code like this`.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? If Sets 1 and 2 do not intersect and the columns involved do not contain keys you could merge the columns containing data from set 1 and 2, resp., into a single one. This would blow up the number of your records and your data model would be less understandable, so again, why would you want to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on where `Set of data 1` and `Set of data2` come from and what their relationship is to each other, and I'm pressed to imagine a real world scenario where this would be a good idea.

A `Set of Data` here is really just a set of `Records` with `Fields`. These `Fields` have, inherently, a relationship to one another which is why they are present on a single `Record`.

---

**Issue 1**: The two sets contain data that don't relate to each other:

`Set of Data1` could be completely disparate from `Set of Data2` and so there is no way to say that they can be combined.

Imagine two sets:

Set1:

```
+-------+--------+
| color | animal |
+-------+--------+
| brown | dog    |
| white | dog    |
| black | dog    |
| green | parrot |
| green | turtle |
| brown | turtle |
+-------+--------+
```

Set2:

```
+------------+--------+
|    food    | flavor |
+------------+--------+
| pepper     | spicy  |
| water      |        |
| grapefruit | bitter |
| lemon      | sour   |
| candy      | sweet  |
+------------+--------+
```

A queries WHERE clause:

```
WHERE (f1, f2) IN (SELECT color, animal FROM set1)
    AND (f3, f4) IN (SELECT food, flavor FROM set2)
```

There's no good way to write this where we test `(f1, f2, f3, f4)` as there is no relationship between `color | animal` and `food | flavor`.

We could, if we were in crazytown, cross join the two sets to get their cartesian product yielding the same result set as the original query:

```
WHERE (f1, f2, f3, f4) IN (SELECT color, animal, food, flavor FROM set1, set2)
```

But now we have a subquery with an intermediate result set of `set1` x `set2` number of records. This is dumb for multiple reasons:

1. Indexes on the two sets are ignored
2. If `set1` or `set2` are more than a few records, you end up with a HUGE intermediate result set.
3. There is no relationship between these two sets, so it's crazy town to combine them just to make your SQL less characters.
4. There will be huge amounts of unnecessary system resources (CPU, Disk, I/O) used to build and store this intermediate result set resulting in a cumbersome slow query.
5. Any other developer upon seeing it will hunt you down and kill you. If they call me up, I'll provide the getaway car.

---

**Issue 2**: The two sets could have a relationship with one another, but changing your `IN` conditions into 1 causes records to drop.

Even if the two sets can be combined, you may still end up with results that differ from the original query. Imagine:

Set1:

```
+-------+--------+
| color | animal |
+-------+--------+
| brown | dog    |
| white | dog    |
| black | dog    |
| green | parrot |
| green | turtle |
| brown | turtle |
+-------+--------+
```

Set 2:

```
+--------+-------------+
| animal | stink_scale |
+--------+-------------+
| turtle |           2 |
| parrot |           4 |
| dog    |           5 |
| skunk  |          10 |
+--------+-------------+
```

Table1:

```
+-------+--------+---------+-------------+
| color | animal | animal2 | stink_scale |
+-------+--------+---------+-------------+
| white | dog    | dog     |           5 |
| brown | dog    | parrot  |           4 |
| green | turtle | turtle  |           2 |
+-------+--------+---------+-------------+
```

The query you want to change:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE (color, animal) IN (SELECT color, animal FROM Set1) 
    AND (animal2, stink_scale) IN (SELECT animal, stink_scale FROM set2);
```

This would yield 3 records as `white | dog` is in `set1` and `dog | 5` is in `set` as it `brown | dog` in `set1` and `parrot | 4` is in `set2` and the same for the third record in `table1`.

BUT if we combine these two sets on their `animal` key:

```
 SELECT set1.color, set1.animal, set2.animal as animal2, set2.stink_scale FROM set1 JOIN set2 ON set1.animal = set2.animal;
```

We will get the set:

```
+-------+--------+---------+-------------+
| color | animal | animal2 | stink_scale |
+-------+--------+---------+-------------+
| brown | dog    | dog     |           5 |
| white | dog    | dog     |           5 |
| black | dog    | dog     |           5 |
| green | parrot | parrot  |           4 |
| green | turtle | turtle  |           2 |
| brown | turtle | turtle  |           2 |
+-------+--------+---------+-------------+
```

And we use that to combine our `IN` conditions:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM table1
 WHERE (color, animal, animal2, stink_scale) IN (SELECT set1.color, set1.animal, set2.animal as animal2, set2.stink_scale FROM set1 JOIN set2 ON set1.animal = set2.animal)
```

We only get 2 records back since there is no result in that subquery where `brown | dog | parrot | 4` will exist.

---

So, in the end unless there is a reason to change the conditions, thus changing the definition of the result set, you probably best off leaving it alone. It really changes the logic.